# I am unable to connect my database in the connection string

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I am a beginner in Visual Studio and in using SQL Server databases.
I have connected my SQL Server database in Server Explorer and tested the connection; it connected successfully.

Now I have a problem adding a row in the database using the Visual Studio coding.
I don't know how to connect to that SQL Server database using that connection string.
I am posting the images for the same.
This is the image with the coding I had used, the Text line which is coloured is

```
(
    cnn.ConnectionString =
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
            "Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication5-20160919115911;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication5-20160919115911.mdf "
        ].ConnectionString;
)
```

[image]

My web.config screen shot is like this.

[image]

The text in the connection string is

```
(    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication5-20160919115911;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication5-20160919115911.mdf" /> )
```

Please guide me what to do.

I had made the database on `localhost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the name of your config entry which is `DefaultConnection` in your case to get it from config file, not the connection string itself, so the correct code is this

```
cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`ConnectionStrings` takes the `name`, not the entire string.

So correct code is `cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name"];`

Answer (score 0):

> The connectionString must be include in appconfig or webconfig (config File)

**Set ConnectionString**

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConStr" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=balbla;IntegratedSecurity=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**GetConnectionString :**

```
cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString;
```